# Asp.Net MVC : Insert data from form collection with List of values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, formcollection

As you can see in picture, I have a form where I continuously add items to the table below.

When I click "Save all" button, it posts all the table values to "**InsertBulk**" method. 
[image]

And this is what I did in my view. I am created a form within the table. Set name and values for each input field. Made the input fields hidden, displayed only text and then on clicking **save all** button it posts all those value to the **InsertBulk** method.

```html
@model FYPPharmAssistant.Models.InventoryModel.Manufacturer

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Form";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{ 
    <label>Name</label><br />
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ManufacturerName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })  <br />
    <label>Description</label><br />
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    <input type="submit" id="addmore" value="add" />
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("InsertBulk", "Manufacturer"))
{
    <table id="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                name &nbsp; &nbsp; 
            </th>
            <th>
                description
            </th>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" id="btnsaveall" value="Save all" />
}

<script>
    $(document).on('ready', function () {
        $('#addmore').on('click', function () {
            var $table = $("#table");            
            $table.append("<tr> <td><input type='hidden' name='ManufacturerName' value='" + $('#ManufacturerName').val() + "' />" + $('#ManufacturerName').val() + "</td> <td><input type='hidden' name='Description' value='" + $('#Description').val() + "'>" + $('#Description').val() + "</td> <td><a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='removeItem(this)'>Remove</a></td></tr>");

            return false;
        });
      });
  </script>
```

This is my **InsertBulk** method.

```js
[HttpPost]
        public void InsertBulk(FormCollection coll)
        {
           
                Manufacturer m = new Manufacturer();
                m.ManufacturerName = coll["ManufacturerName"];
                m.Description = coll["Description"];
                db.Manufacturers.Add(m);
                db.SaveChanges();
          
          }
```

**Result :**
Ans this is what I get in Result. How am I suppose to solve this ? Please help!

[image]

I also tried to count keys and loop through each in the **InsertBulk** method. But I think I did it all wrong.

```html
 int count = coll.Count;
            

              if(count == 0)
              {
                  return View("ChamForm", "Test");
              }
              else
              {
                  for(int i = 0; i<count; i++)
                  {
                      Manufacturer m = new Manufacturer();
                      m.ManufacturerName = coll["ManufacturerName[" + i + "]"];
                      m.Description = coll["Description[" + i + "]"];
                      db.Manufacturers.Add(m);
                      db.SaveChanges();
                  }
              }*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is so why not split contents based on comma, save each of them in two different string array. Then loop through each array's item saving name and description on each loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult Student(StudentModel model, FormCollection frm)
    {
        string XmlData = "<Parent>";


        var stuclass = frm.GetValues("stuclass");
        var InstituteId = frm.GetValues("Institute");
        var obtmark = frm.GetValues("obtmark");
        var totalmark = frm.GetValues("totalmark");
        var per = frm.GetValues("per");

        int count = stuclass.Count();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            XmlData += "<child><stuclass>" + stuclass[i] + "</stuclass>"
                            + "<InstituteId>" + InstituteId[i] + "</InstituteId>"
                             + "<obtmark>" + obtmark[i] + "</obtmark>"
                             + "<totalmark>" + totalmark[i] + "</totalmark>"
                             + "<per>" + per[i] + "</per>"
                               + "</child>";
        }
        XmlData += "</Parent>";
        model.XmlData = XmlData;
        var res = studal.Insertdtl(model);

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please click on [edit] and add some words summarising how your code addresses the question, or perhaps explain how your answer differs from the previous answer/answers. Thanks